How to disable webcam access via RegEdit for StreamLabs specifically?
I'm having a problem with StreamLabs where it accesses the webcam (turns on the webcam light) every single time I open the program, even when I'm not telling the software to use the webcam. It's very frustrating and I've had no luck with re-installing Streamlabs/clearing cache, so it must be a Windows issue.
I think I found the right RegEdit entry for modifying camera access here:
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\webcam\NonPackaged\C:#Program Files#Streamlabs OBS#resources#app.asar.unpacked#node_modules#obs-studio-node#obs64.exe
In this folder, I have (Default), LastUsedTimeStart, an LastUsedTimeStop. What file do I need to create/modify in order to deny webcam access to this software?
screenshot of StreamLabs folder
Thanks.
